# How can i find the n largest integers in an array and returns them in a new array

Tags: c#, .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

How can i find the n largest integers in an array and returns them in a new array.

Comment: Why `axapta`, `dynamics-ax-2012` and `x++` tags?

Comment: A solution using jobs in Dynamics ax is also fine for me. I need best possible solution for this. So I added Dynamics AX.

Comment: That's not a question, it's a demand. Stackoverflow is a question/answer site.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for an answer for that question i posted.

Comment: Please note the [on-topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) linked in the Help, which says "Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq is very simple:

```
var newArray = array.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(n).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please let me know if this is in(works in) C#?

Comment: yes, this is in C#

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in nlogn time with heapsort.

1. Create a max-heap
2. Pull n elements from it